# How to design this table using html

Tags: html

[image]

I have a requirement to design a table like an above image.

Please help me anybody or have any ideas to design this table.

Thanks,
Ashraf

Comment: search for google hwo to create table or <table><tr><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>5</td></tr></table>

Comment: its something different...It has an order border...!

Comment: Hi @Ashraf can u  add more code in your question or create a fiddle

Comment: Hi Rohit,here is my Jsfiddle code-- http://jsfiddle.net/Ashraf1989/ouo6zuu9/

Comment: I wants to design the table as I uploaded here with outer border.

Comment: as like this http://jsfiddle.net/ouo6zuu9/1/

Comment: Hi now used to this css in your table table{border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;}

Comment: Thanks Rohit, but I think u didn't checked my image....I need exactly the same table.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark up the `table` as normal, but place it inside a `custom-table` `<div>`. The `custom-table` `<div>` contains four `custom-border` `<div>`s which, given a higher `z-index`, each overlap the outermost cells of the original `table`.

```css
table {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
margin: 0;
}

td {
width: 50px;
height: 38px;
border:1px solid rgba(127,127,127,1);
text-align: center;
}

.custom-table {
position: relative;
display:inline-block;
width: 160px;
height: 206px;
}

.custom-border {
position: absolute;
z-index: 12;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.horizontal {
width: 160px;
height: 30px;
}

.vertical {
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 206px;
}

.custom-border:nth-of-type(-n+2) {
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.custom-border:nth-of-type(3) {
top: 0;
right: 0;
}

.custom-border:nth-of-type(4) {
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-table">

<div class="custom-border horizontal"></div>
<div class="custom-border vertical"></div>

<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>4</td>
<td>4</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>5</td>
<td>5</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</table>

<div class="custom-border vertical"></div>
<div class="custom-border horizontal"></div>

</div>
```